# Adding PHP mixed with HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

I guess this is really simple for you guys but I have been trying to make this work for hours now and have yet to succeed.

I am trying to modify the comments template for a WordPress theme. All I want to do is add a specific piece of PHP code so that the avatar of the user in the comments section will have a link.

The original code to display the avatar in WordPress is:

```
<div class="comment-avatar"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 65 ); ?></div>
```

All I need to do now is add the following PHP code to the above line:

```
<a href="'.$userpro->permalink( $comment->user_id ).'">' XXX </a>
```

XXX is where the first line of code should go. Since this is a mix of PHP and HTML, I get very confused.

Can any of you guys please help me out on this one? I would appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: Have you tried `<div class="comment-avatar"><a href="<?php echo $userpro->permalink( $comment->user_id ); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 65 ); ?></a></div>`?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are trying to do

```
<a href="<?php echo $userpro->permalink( $comment->user_id )?>">
    <div class="comment-avatar"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 65 ); ?></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked :) But I used Charlotte Dunois solution since it <a> tag is inside the <div> tag, making it more clean :)

But thanks a lot for all your help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="'.$userpro->permalink( $comment->user_id ).'"><div class="comment-avatar">' . get_avatar( $comment, 65 ) . '</div></a>';
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the answer was php code that the user requested

Comment: Your answer would me more useful if you edit it to explain how it works and why it answers the question.